# pass the ajax data processed to route Laravel 6.x

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes, pass-data

I want pass the ajax data processed to route but i don't know do it. 
Here this my code ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('order.by.status') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    _token: _token,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    sell_buy: sell_buy,
                    status: status,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tbody_data').html('');
                    $.each(data.orders, function (key, value) {
                        $('#tbody_data').append(    `<tr>
                            <td>${ key +1 }</td>
                            <td style="color:#007a6e">
                                <b>${ value.code_deal }</b><br>
                                <a style="font-size: 12px;" href="{{ route('order.by.status', value.id) }}">Detail</a>
                                // I want pass id to href of route this but Fail
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>${ value.name }</b>
                                <br> ${ value.phone }
                            </td>
                            <td>${ value.content }</td>
                        </tr>`)
                        });
                }
            });
```

This is route:

```
Route::post('order_by_status','Backend\StatusController@getOrderByStatus')->name('order.by.status');
```

Please help me!
Thanks!!!

Comment: From the info given your route is a `POST` route and wouldn't work with `<a href></a>` (`GET`) anyway. Add a field in your results/processed data that "calculates" the URL you want and use that in your JS

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "post",
            url: "/order_by_status",
```

i use for pass the ajax data processed to route-> headers(try it)